# Wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) error when calling markdown method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown

All,

I just created markdown_title and markdown_body methods. When I go to the show view page for my Post model I am getting the error:  Wrong number of arguments.

I believe my markdown_title method(also for markdown_body) might be constructed incorrectly below in the post.rb file. Is this the culprit?:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  has_one :summary
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :topic
  #has_one :summary
  default_scope {order('created_at DESC')}

  validates :title, length: {minimum: 5},  presence: true
  validates :body,  length: {minimum: 20}, presence: true
  validates :topic, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true


 def markdown_title
(render_as_markdown).render(self.title).html_safe
end


def markdown_body
(render_as_markdown).render(self.body).html_safe
end

private

def render_as_markdown
renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new
extensions = {fenced_code_blocks: true}
redcarpet = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
#return redcarpet
end


end
```

Here is my code for my show.html.erb file where the error is appearing while calling my markdown_title method:

```
    <h1><%= @post.markdown_title @post.title %></h1>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
    <p><%= @post.body %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn    btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    </div>

    <% if @post.summary.present? %>

    <h1>Post Summary</h1>
    <p><%= @post.summary.body %></p>

    <% else %>

  <%= form_for [@topic, @post, @post.build_summary] do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

This is the Post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  #def index #for the index page
      #@posts = Post.all 
      #authorize @posts  
  #end

  def show
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  end

  def new
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
      @post = Post.new
        authorize @post #authorize() will check the policy on new post resources
       # if user is present it wll let it render if no user present itll give exception
  end

  def create
    #@post = Post.new(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body))
    #require and permit make sure only certain keys are passed to Post.new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    #@post = current_user.posts.build(params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body))
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    @post.topic = @topic
    authorize @post #authorize() will check if user is logged in if not itll give an exception

    if @post.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your new post was created and saved."
      redirect_to [@topic, @post] #takes you to the new post you created
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :new # it grabs the new.html.erb file and pastes it in the view
    end
  end


  def edit
      @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      authorize @post
  end

  def update
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    #@post_check = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    authorize @post

    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Post was updated and captured your new update."
      redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
  end

end
```

Here is the error I get on my view:
[image]

Comment: #saintClair33 you dont need to pass argument like `<h1><%= @post.markdown_title @post.title %></h1>`  as it takes the title from it self . use like `<h1><%= @post.markdown_title %></h1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your `markdown_title` method with a parameter, in this case, `@post.title`.

```
<h1><%= @post.markdown_title @post.title %></h1>
```

In the definition of your `Post` class, the `markdown_title` method doesn't take any parameters.

```
 def markdown_title
   (render_as_markdown).render(self.title).html_safe
 end
```

That's why you're seeing the `Wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error.

Since you're already referencing `self.title` in the `markdown_title` method, there's no reason to pass `@post.title` to it. Just remove `@post.title` from where you're calling `markdown_title`, and you should be good to go.